# How to show Initiative and Feature as column in TFS backlog

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

Is it possible to get the Initiatives and Features to show up in the columns for a given PBI? I have tried creating a field on the PBI WITD that I could copy the values into but I can't see where to get them from.

Using TFS 2013 Update 4 with Visual Studio SCRUM 2013.4 Process Template

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an answer to your question, but you can click on View at the top right, and select a mapping to the higher levels.  Of course, your photo shows "Backlog items" while mine shows "User Stories", so they may be completely different versions, or something.[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I realise that is there. I was trying to show them as a column so it was easy to see where in the roadmap the PBI existed when queries are being run. All my research points to it being impossible.